# set timeout for session using zend

Tags: zend-framework, session-timeout, zend-auth

How do you renew a session everytime a user requests a page?I am using the code below but does not seem to be working.

```
$zend_authNS = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$zend_authNS->setExpirationSeconds( 3600);
```

This will expire the no matter what, if the user is clicking on diffrente pages or if it is inactive.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$zend_authNS->setExpirationHops(1);
```

Would be the normal way to expire a session on each page request.

You seem to be using Zend_Auth, so I wonder if this can be accomplished using the storage component of Zend_Auth, maybe:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->getNamespace()->setExpirationHops(1);
```

Haven't tried it but it might work.

Comment: i am still not able to come up with a working code for this. What i need is to check for the inactivity of the user. If the user is inactive log the user out and kill the session. Can someone provide a sample code? the one above is not working. thank you.

Comment: That requires javascript. PHP and ZF can detect hops and elapsed time. To test for inactivity will require client side code.